# Error:Passing address of non-scalar object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

Tags: ios

[image]

I am trying to plot bar chart using PowerPlot library. So for I have found only this code to match my requirement for negative bars and with shading or opacity. The original sample project doesn't use ARC. But my project uses ARC. On copying same code I got a lot of errors on compiling my project. Some of them were just autorelease or retain that I have cleared. Now I am getting like this: Passing address of non-scalar object to _autoreleasing argument. I dont know how to solve this. Is there some quick way to fix this ? Or suggest me some good sample code or tutorial for drawing bars that also have negative value and shading color within the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Build phase->compiler sources` And add

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

To your classes which is non arc.